# Has anyone peer-review researched investors buying another, but similarly spelled, ticker?

Tags: stock-market

[GLDD - Believing Robinhood users are dumb is profitable... : wallstreetbets](https://old.reddit.com/r/wallstreetbets/comments/i3k19r/gldd_believing_robinhood_users_are_dumb_is/)

> Academics need to research the correlation between performing tickers and their closely related (only in name) cousins.

1. Have any academics done so?
2. Has any forensic linguist investigated the morphological traits behind such "false friends"?

E.g. in February 2020, many investors misconstrued [ZOOM for their desired ZM (Zoom Video Communications)](https://time.com/5792310/zoom-zm-stocks-coronavirus/). Similarly, I wonder if some investors misconstrued [GLDD (Great Lakes Dredge and Dock Company) for their desired GLD](https://redd.it/i3k19r), or [KDKN (Kodiak Energy) for their desired KODK (Eastman Kodak Company)](https://old.reddit.com/r/wallstreetbets/comments/i3k19r/gldd_believing_robinhood_users_are_dumb_is/g0cfu0r/).

Comment: “Google scholar” could probably help. It’s pretty hard to see how the research would be anything other than a collection of anecdotes. That’s journalism, not finance research.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this has been done. [Balashov and Nikiforov (2019)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1386418118303094) studied firms with similar tickers and found 25% had comovement in turnover and estimated 5% of turnover was due to investor confusion